# cx_Oracle returns empty query when using bindings

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I'm facing a strange problem when doing queries in my sql application. I'm working with python3 and cx_Oracle 5.1.2. My test table is organized as it follows:

> CREATE TABLE  people (
>   sin           CHAR(15),
>   name          VARCHAR(40),
>   PRIMARY KEY (sin))

with the following values inserted (sin, name):

> ('1','a'), ('2','b'), ('3','c')

When I do a simple select using an unsafe query:

> curs.execute("select name from people where sin = '1'")

The result is 'a', as expected, but if I use bindings:

> curs.execute("select name from people where sin = :v", v='1')

The result is empty. I already tried to change this to the positional '?' parameter, set the size of 'v' through setinputsizes(v=15) but nothing appears to work.

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure - have you tried `curs.execute("select name from people where sin = :v", {'v':'1'})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your use of the CHAR datatype instead of VARCHAR2.

You can observe the difference even in SQL*Plus.

If we bind a VARCHAR2 variable then no rows are selected:

```
SQL> variable v varchar2(15)
SQL> exec :v := '1';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select name from people where sin = :v;

no rows selected
```

If instead we bind a CHAR variable, which is the same data type as the column, then one row is selected:

```
SQL> variable v char(15)
SQL> exec :v := '1';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select name from people where sin = :v;

NAME
----------------------------------------
a
```

Therefore you either need to change the column data type from CHAR to VARCHAR2 (by the way, VARCHAR is obsolete as well) or instruct cx_Oracle to user a FIXED_CHAR data type:

```
>>> v = curs.var(cx_Oracle.FIXED_CHAR, 15)
>>> v.setvalue(0, '1')
>>> print v
<cx_Oracle.FIXED_CHAR with value '1'>

>>> result = curs.execute("select name from people where sin = :sin", sin=v)
>>> for r in result: print r

('a',)
```